incorrect balance

Hi, I'm trying to learn about solana development, following the youtube videos of solana bootcamp (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P8JeL3TURU)
When I use 'solana balance' and running the script, the address is the same and correct, but the balance is very different, which might lead to other errors...

What is the solution? I am experiencing the same issue. My RPC URL matches my localhost. export const connection = new Connection('http://localhost:8899', 'confirmed'); Any advice?

This is an old post, but in future, can you please use text for console output?

Make sure the network you're connected to is the same. You can see in solana config get that your network is set as localhost, while in the script you're running it is set to Devnet.
For the script you're running, you can update to point to local by setting the RPC_URL to be your localhost. like:
export const CLUSTER_URL = http://localhost:8899

